# Laravel troubles with WHERE in relationships

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm having trouble when a user is not an *admin*. The goal is to get only those requests that belong to the user, but when I use the `where` clause, I get all the requests from the DB.
It was supposed to get all the requests only for an *admin*.

Thank you for the help!

```
public function index(){
    $status = request('status', -1);
    $paper_size = request('paper_size', -1);

    if (auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
        $requests = Request::
            where('paper_size', $paper_size)->orWhereRaw($paper_size. ' = -1')->
            where('status', $status)->orWhereRaw($status. ' = -1')->


            orderBy(
                request('orderby') ? request('orderby') : 'created_at',
                request('order') ? request('order') : 'DESC'
            )->paginate(10);

        $departments = Departament::All();


        return view('Requests.index', compact('requests', 'departments'));
    }

    $requests = auth()->user()->requests()->
        where('status', $status)->orWhereRaw($status. ' = -1')->
        where('paper_size', $paper_size)->orWhereRaw($paper_size. ' = -1')->
        orderBy(
            request('orderby') ? request('orderby') : 'created_at',
            request('order') ? request('order') : 'DESC'
        )->paginate(10);

        return view('Requests.index', compact('requests'));
}
```

UPDATE:

I can already list all user requests, but the status filter does not work.

Ps: the filter "paper_size" is working as expected

SOLVED:

Thanks to the whole community, and especially to @Sandeesh

```
    public function index(){
    request('status') == -1 || request('status') == null ?
        $statusExists = false : $statusExists = true;
    $status = request('status');

    request('paper_size') == -1 || request('paper_size') == null ?
        $paper_sizeExists = false : $paper_sizeExists = true;
    $paper_size = request('paper_size');

    $is_admin = auth()->user()->isAdmin();

    $requests = Request::when($statusExists, function ($query) use ($status) {
        return $query->where('status', $status);
    })
        ->when($paper_sizeExists, function ($query) use ($paper_size) {
            return $query->where('paper_size', $paper_size);
        })
        ->when(!$is_admin, function ($query) {
            return $query->where('owner_id', auth()->id());
        })
        ->orderBy(request('orderby', 'created_at'), request('order', 'desc'))
        ->paginate(10);

    if (!$is_admin) {
        return view('Requests.index', compact('requests'));
    }

    $departments = Departament::all();

    return view('Requests.index', compact('requests', 'departments'));
}
```

Comment: First of all, remove that image and paste the code here, then select the code and press the `{}` icon to indent the code. Then, remove web tag because you only need help with SQL and Laravel.

Comment: Done, thanks for the tip

Comment: It may not be a good idea to have a model class named Request. That is also the name of the [HTTP Request class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests).

Comment: @BLDD does the requests table have `user_id` column? or is it a many to many relationship? Also you need to wrap the where and orwhere conditions inside a single where.

Comment: @Sandeesh yes, the table have user_id. the relationship is  the User has many Requests but a Request only belongs to one User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `where` and `orWhereRaw` conditions together for a single column. Or use `when` instead of the workaround you apply with `-1 = -1`. I've also refactored the code for you.

```
public function index()
{
    $status = request('status');
    $paper_size = request('paper_size');

    $is_admin = auth()->user()->isAdmin();

    $requests = Request::when(!is_null($status), function ($query) use ($status) {
            return $query->where('status', $status);
        })
        ->when(!is_null($paper_size), function ($query) use ($paper_size) {
            return $query->where('paper_size', $paper_size);
        })
        ->when(!$is_admin, function ($query) {
            return $query->where('owner_id', auth()->id());
        })
        ->orderBy(request('orderby', 'created_at'), request('order', 'desc'))
        ->paginate(10);

    if (!$is_admin) {
        return view('Requests.index', compact('requests'));
    }

    $departments = Departament::all();

    return view('Requests.index', compact('requests', 'departments'));
}
```

Comment: Now the query returns the user's requests, but if you select a status or paper_size the returned requests are 0.
Nice tip to reduce code btw

Comment: Dump `$status`, `$paper_size` and `$is_admin` and show me the result. With and without them being selected.

Comment: without being selected: (as user)
$status => null
$paper_size => null
$is_admin => false

selected:
$status => 2
$paper_size => 3
$is_admin => false

|||
i have 3 status => 0, 1, and 2
and 2 paper_size => 3,4

Comment: Replace `paginate(10)` with `toSql()` and then dump `$requests` to check the query formed on each case. From the input result you've given me, the code should work just fine. Make sure  you have results for those conditions in your db.

Comment: without select -> "select * from `requests` where `owner_id` = ? order by `created_at` desc"

withselect -> "select * from `requests` where `paper_size` = ? and `owner_id` = ? order by `created_at` desc"

ps: i selected the status 0, when i select other status the query is:

"select * from `requests` where `status` = ? and `paper_size` = ? and `owner_id` = ? order by `created_at` desc"

Comment: Does `owner_id` hold the user id? I'll update my query since you need 0 conditions on your search values.

Comment: i discover the problem, when i dont select the status for example, the link is:

http://projeto.ainet/requests?orderby=created_at&order=DESC+selected&status=-1&paper_size=3

and is supposed to be:

http://projeto.ainet/requests?orderby=created_at&order=DESC+selected&paper_size=3

Comment: I just updated the code to handle 0 value as a valid input.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the `$user_id = Auth::id` and then update the second query to have a `where user_id = $user_id` statement (I'm not sure which of those tables belongs to the user).

Comment: i tried this and i get the requests from my user, but when i select the status or paper_size and filter that i still get all the requests from the DB

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$requests = Request::with('User')
    ->where('user_id',\Auth::user()->user_id)
    ->where('status', $status)
    ->orWhereRaw($status. ' = -1')
    ->where('paper_size', $paper_size)
    ->orWhereRaw($paper_size. ' = -1')
    ->orderBy(request('orderby') ? request('orderby') : 'created_at',
              request('order') ? request('order') : 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: i still get all the requests, only the paper_size  where works

Comment: Delete this line: ->orWhereRaw($status. ' = -1')

Comment: Are you sure there are any record with diff status?